# Change an elements CSS value within a node.js module

Tags: node.js

How can I change an HTML element CSS value from within a node.js module?

I have a raspberry pi setup with node.js and have physical buttons (hardware) which when pressed turn on LED's but I would also like to change the HTML on screen to reflect what happens when a button is pressed.

I can changed screen CSS using the below code in javascript but I don't seem to be able to do the same for node.js.

```
var highlightItem = '#someID';
$(highlightItem).css('border-style', 'solid');
$(highlightItem).css('border-color', 'red');
```

Thanks

**EDIT**

I still can't do what I wanted... I'm using express.io and have the examples working just fine but I can't integrate them into my project so thought it better to ask for some assistance again.... please.

My app.js looks like this:

```
var controller = require('custom/controllerModule');
var buttons = require('custom/pushButton');
var app = require('express.io')();
app.http().io();

app.get('/pushButtonWatchOff', buttons.pushButtonWatchOff);
app.get('/pushButtonWatchOn', buttons.pushButtonWatchOn);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
});

// Setup the ready route, and emit talk event.
app.io.route('ready', function(req) {
    req.io.emit('talk', {
        message: 'io event from an io route on the server'
})
})

// Send the client html.
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/views/index.html')
})


app.listen(3000);

console.log('Running');
```

And my index.html looks like:

```
<script>
    $.get('/pushButtonWatchOn', {pinNumberOn: 4, pinNumberOff: 17});

    io = io.connect()

    // Emit ready event.
    io.emit('ready') 

    // Listen for the talk event.
    io.on('talk', function(data) {
        alert(data.message)
    })
</script>
```

This all works ok and displays an alert message when the screen is refreshed but I'd like the screen message to display when I click on one of the hardware buttons from the Raspberry Pi.

The hardware button code looks like this (and works ok):

```
var Gpio = require('onoff').Gpio;
var pinNumberOff;
var pinNumberOn;

exports.pushButtonWatchOn = function(req, res){
    pinNumberOff = parseInt(req.query.pinNumberOff);
    pinNumberOn = parseInt(req.query.pinNumberOn);
    pushButtonWatchOn();
    res.json(200, {message: 'success'});

}

function pushButtonWatchOn(){

    console.log("\nWaiting For User Interation");
    console.log("Push Button Active Pin: " + pinNumberOn);
    console.log("Current State: Off");

    pushButtonOn = new Gpio(pinNumberOn, 'in', 'both');

    pushButtonOn.watch(function (err, value) {

    if (err) throw err;

    console.log("\nPush Button Pressed Using Pin: " + pinNumberOn);
    console.log(__dirname);

    pushButtonOn.unexport();

    pushButtonWatchOff();

    });
}
```

So can anyone help me out with getting an alert to display when a button is pressed?

Thanks

Comment: Node is a webserver and your page is on a browser. They must communicate somehow to work. You cannot execute code on browser from server, without browser asking for it. To communicate you can use socket.io(websockets) and express for serving webpages. You can send messages to browser on button press from node and on browser listen to messages and change css accordingly.

Comment: Ok, I did start to look at socket.io but it seemed overly complicated for what I wanted to do. I also found cheerio but I can't get that to work at the moment.

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: cheerio is only for executing jquery on node. You will also have to make node send the page/results back. Websockets fit the realtime requirements of your app.

Comment: Ah, ok... I'll look at socket.io again.

Comment: Shameless bump after a main post edit....